# Dynamic update variable values which are computed inside the method but used outside

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a beginner level programmer; I've a small query.

I've an String array whose size is determined under a method (say method A()) , after computing the user provided information.

before defining the string array, I've called the method (method A()) which is responsible to compute the size variable.

That String array (say Str[]) is used in multiple methods so I've to define that variable in the class outside of those methods.

***The problem is when the user change the values inside method A() (by Textfield inputs) the size variable doesn't update automatically ***

Is there any way to dynamically update the size variable whenever the values are changed by the user ?

Summary of my program is written below;

```
class my class
 {
    int size = A(); 
     String[] str = new String[size];

     int A() //invokes when the user clicks a button "Sum"
     {

     row = jTextField1 + jTextField2;
       return size;
       }

        void B() //invokes when the user clicks a button "Show"
        {
        //print str[]
        }

        void C()//invokes when the user clicks a button "Fetch"
        {
        //fetch value from Database & store into str[]
        }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the array is not going to change size after initialization, you can simply initialize it in method A (and check for null in other places where it is used)

```
class myClass {
    String[] str;

    void A() {
        int size = field1 + field2;
        str = new String[size];
    }

    void B() {
        if( str == null ) return;
        // else use str
    }
}
```

If the array is truly dynamic, you should look at using a Collection instead (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/).

Answer (score 0):

Assign the new value of the variable to the same instance you had.

```
  int A() //invokes when the user clicks a button "Sum"
  {

   row = jTextField1 + jTextField2;
   size = row;
   return size;
   }
```

The same goes to other attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what your graphical interface is, but I'll guess it's a Swing application.

What you are trying to do is called an [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) : Your field won't automatically update if you don't specify which action must be run when your text field is updated.

You need to add a Listener to your textfield, through this syntax :

```
jTextField1.addListener(yourClassContainingSomeActionMethod);
```

This listener is a class which MUST contains a method called **update()**. Whenever the jTextField value will be modified, it knows your class is attached to it, and it will run its update() method.

In your case, the update() method adds the jTextFields (1&2) values to return an int, used to specify a new String length ; so, you will have to put this class as a listener on the other jTtexField2 too. You should check too if your fields contains integers, otherwise you will get a nasty error if anyone inputs some text.